# Sitecore deployment to Azure

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I am working with Sitecore, created a website using it. Now i want to deploy it to Azure. Can anyone please suggest me the approach, expenditure and the process to deploy Sitecore to Azure?

Help appreciated
Thanks

Comment: This is a little bit broad...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Sitecore Azure module, you can find the documentation here: https://doc.sitecore.net/cloud/azure/

Read this to get started: https://doc.sitecore.net/cloud/azure/getting%20started%20with%20sitecore%20azure

You will have to build that into your Sitecore implementation.

You can also just use the Azure VMs and create a virtual data center to host on. That would be very similar to standard hosting.

Answer (score 0):

The exact Azure implementation guide depends on if you are going to use Sitecore Azure module or not. I am going to provide you with few more links with very important information you need to read consider prior taking the decision:

http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2013/10/sitecore-in-windows-azure/

https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/azure/310/getting_started_with_sitecore_azure_310-a4.pdf

http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/jakob-leander/posts/2013/01/why-we-love-sitecore-on-azure.aspx

http://mhwelander.net/2014/09/23/sitecore-azure-for-beginners-part-1-what-is-microsoft-azure/

Please also read next article for compatibility check - will your bespoke solution fit Azure?
http://techitpro.com/sitecore-azure/

10 Considerations for a Successful Sitecore Azure Implementation - A Step-by-Step Guide:
http://www.perficient.com/securedocs/1841191041051161013211297112101114115.pdf

Also consider your hosting options and the way you are going to do the deployment (both code and packages). There is a good article on that:

http://blog.petersondave.com/sitecore/azure/Alternate-Sitecore-8-Azure-Deployment-Options/
http://www.cmsbestpractices.com/choosing-the-right-hosting-option-for-sitecore/

I think this list gives you enough food for thoughts and hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should first check if your solution (with different modules) is compatible with Azure: 
https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/201557